# How do I target the InnerText of a custom PowerAutomate Desktop Selector

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to understand the custom selector function for a web ui button. I essentially just want to target a button that has "Add to account" as the value. That should be just the InnerText right? It's not in the VIsual Editor so I am trying to do with the custom. Is it `button[innerText="Add to Account"]?` Struggling to get that to work right now.

Here is the markup

```
<button data-ng-if="vm.userPermissions.accountOnly" data-ng-disabled="!vm.canFinish || !vm.hasFeeSchedule" class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" data-ng-click="vm.accountOnly()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add to Account</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out.   `button:contains("Add to Account")`